# parsing CSV file in java with " in the CSV file

Tags: java, regex, csv

My CSV file has following text:

```
a, b, 0, "0, 1, 2", ""ab cd", 5", 10
```

My regex:

```
aColumnValue = dataRow.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

where aColumnValue is a String array.

This regex is failing since on the '"' before ab the regex closes and searches for the next token.

Please help find the correct regex.

The correct count of tokens should be: 6
and the actual tokens should be

```
a
b
0
0, 1, 2,
"ab cd", 5
10
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not parse CSV using regex. Use libraries that know to do this well. For example [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I figured out there could be hell lot many issues in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more issues. You should use some CSV parser like opencsv http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I figured out there could be hell lot many issues in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "a, b, 0, \"0, 1, 2\", \"\"ab cd\", 5\", 10";
String[] parts = input.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
```

The `parts` variable contains:

```
a
 b
 0
 "0, 1, 2"
 ""ab cd", 5"
 10
```

Likely you need to remove `"` and spaces.